# System command with Rails on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've deployed my Rails application to Heroku following https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3 and can open a website like http://severe-mountain-793.herokuapp.com

In my controller, I have a system command

```
`wget ...`
```

but it gives the error

```
sh: wget: not found
```

What should I do to use the command?

Comment: why do you need to use system commands? Why can't use use net::http?

Comment: @JohnBeynon I need to do recursive downloading, which net::http doesn't provide as far as I know.

Comment: you're downloading into your heroku application? What are you doing?

Comment: @JohnBeynon Yes, downloading into `/tmp` folder. I'm serving some content to the user.

Comment: so you're aware that they will only have 30 seconds to download it from your Heroku application else the request will be timed out?

Comment: @JohnBeynon Yup, I'm aware of that. I still want to run `wget`. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: so if wget isn't available, you'll have to install it via a custom buildpack.

Comment: https://github.com/holiture/heroku-buildpack-tex is a good one to look at - using multiple buildpacks you can use the default ruby pack and then your custom one to add the packages you need.

Comment: @JohnBeynon Could you please give an answer with details on how to do this? It would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you'll need to use a custom buildpack to achieve this which will grab wget, compile it and then include the resultant binary into your slug (a heroku term).

Turns out, I've just whipped one up - https://github.com/johnbeynon/heroku-buildpack-wget.

To use;

create a `.buildpacks` file in the root of your project containing

```
git://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
git://github.com/johnbeynon/heroku-buildpack-wget.git
```

and then do

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=git://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi.git
```

Now, when you deploy your application, it will use the heroku-buildpack-multi which will read your .buildpacks file and use those defined in there. heroku-buildpack-ruby is the default provided ruby buildpack and then mine will add wget into your application.

to verify if it's work, do `heroku run bash` and then try and run `wget` and see if it works.

Comment: John.. awesome! Could you please write one for me for the `zip` command as well? It's the last one I'll need. You clearly deserve a bounty for all this work. Thanks so much.

Comment: I've also created a new thread to make it more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310120/custom-buildpack-for-zip-in-heroku