# Custom buildpack for zip in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I would like to use the `zip` system command in Heroku, but it is not available. I don't understand how to write a custom buildpack by myself. Could someone please point me to an existing buildpack for `zip` or write a new one for me? In [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305863/system-command-with-rails-on-heroku), John Beynon wrote a [custom buildpack](https://github.com/johnbeynon/heroku-buildpack-wget) for the `wget` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zipping you can do with pure ruby, I did it myself last week to zip a folder recursively using https://github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip